¿Comor retornar mensajes de error o exito en distintos metodos cuando se usa inertia + laravel 11 + vue3?
Estoy creando un pequeño crud con laravel inertia y vue 3 todo monolitico no estoy usando apis. Resulta que eh creado un controller para eliminar usuarios
 public function destroy($id)
    {
        try {
            $delete = $this->userService->deleteUser($id);
            if ($delete) {
                return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', 'Usuario eliminado correctamente');
            }
            return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('error', 'Error al eliminar usuario');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return InertiaResponse::handleServerError('users/IndexUsers');
        }
    }

funciona me deja eliminar el registro
ahora la cosa es que se supone estoy retornando al index y enviando un mensaje flash
eh el front end tengo esta funcion

const props = defineProps({
    users: Object,
    term: String,
});

function deleteItem(user) {
    console.log('delete', user);

    router.delete(`/dashboard/users/${user}`, {
        preserveState: true,
      
        onSuccess: page => {
            console.log(page)
        },
        onError: errors => {
            console.log(errors)
        },
       
    })
}

ahi eh colocado un console.log para ver que me devuelve pero no veo que este retornando mis mensajes flash. ¿Entonces mi pregunta es como accedo a esos mensajes flash que estoy enviando?
Eh probadop de todo pero no logro hacerlo
El boton para eliminar es
<button class="btn btn-icon btn-danger" @click="deleteItem(user.id)">
                                                    <em class="icon ni ni-trash"></em>
                                                </button>

se que si agrego el mensaje en la funcion deleteItem podria facilmente agregarlo a un alert o lo que sea para mostrar el mensaje de exito pero quisiera poder retornar el mensaje que obtengo del controller. Pero nada de lo que eh intentado ah servido. ¿Que estoy mal?
